# Dll injection overlay DirectX version

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directx-9, directx-10

I'm working on screenshot application for full-screen DirectX games.
But there is one problem - for every version of DirectX there is own way to make screenshot (as far as I understand).

So the question is how to determine DirectX version of application which I injects with my DLL from this DLL?

Comment: directx doesnt handle screenshots itself, the game does. So yeah, it's different per game what key they use

Comment: In addition to @GillBates comment, after your dll is injected, you will have to invoke a remote thread, compete with other process threads, scan the process memory for transient resources, and attempt to correctly decipher the device context.  Make no mistake, you will crash the target program most of time.

Comment: You will also likely be considered suspected malware by security software and anti-cheat/anti-piracy schemes. I don't understand why there are so many people writing the same thing over and over again here which has already been done quite successfully by FRAPS et al. Besides, most DirectX games these days support 'fake fullscreen' which is a borderless window and standard snip works on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple trick to determine the actual DirectX version in my DirectX hooks is to call GetModuleHandle for each of the dx dlls. For instance:

```
HINSTANCE hD3D11 = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("D3D11.DLL"));
if (hD3D11)
{
    // DirectX 11 dll is loaded, so we can hook D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain and/or D3D11CreateDevice
}
```

And the same or similar for D3D10.dll and D3D9.dll. I think the best way is to try GetModuleHandle in the following order: d3d11.dll, d3d10.dll and d3d9.dll. 
This approach works well for the DX hooks I created. I hope it will work for you too, or you have to adjust it for your purposes. Of course you should first inject the above code that checks the DX version and after that decide which DXhook dll to inject according to the version.

Comment: Yeh, I came to this decision couple of days before. Anyway thanks. Marked you as answer.